# Sending email at a predefined time

Tags: windows-xp, email-client

Is there an email client (if somebody knows how to do this in Gmail, also interested in that) that allows writing a mail, and sending it at a predefined time in the future? Say, I write a mail at 2 a.m. and the client (computer is always on) sends it at 8 a.m. the same day (while I'm most probably sleeping).

Comment: @Dennis - good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [add-ons to Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/search/?q=send+later&cat=1,50&lver=any&pid=1&sort=&pp=20&lup=&advanced=) that provide this capability.